# product of all columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a data frame like this

```
aa = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(1,1,1), z=c(3,2,1))
```

How could I get the pairwise product of all the columns in dplyr?
It would be trivial if I know all the column names in the data frame. I'd just call a regular mutate()

```
aa = aa %>%
 mutate(prod=x*y*z)
```

But suppose I do not know the column names and number of columns, what would be a programmatic way to get the product of all columns (pairwise multiplication of all columns)?

Answer (score 2):

We could use `reduce` with `*`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
aa %>% 
   mutate(prod = reduce(., `*`))
```

-output

```
#  x y z prod
#1 1 1 3    3
#2 2 1 2    4
#3 3 1 1    3
```

---

Or using `pmap` with `prod`

```
aa %>% 
    mutate(prod = pmap_dbl(., prod))
```

---

Or with `base R` using `Reduce`

```
aa$prod <- Reduce(`*`, aa)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be using `c_across()`:

```
library(dplyr)
#Data
aa = data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c(1,1,1), z=c(3,2,1))
#Code
aa %>% mutate(id=1:n()) %>%
  rowwise(id) %>% mutate(product=prod(c_across(x:z)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Rowwise:  id
     id     x     y     z product
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1     1     1     3       3
2     2     2     1     2       4
3     3     3     1     1       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Another base R option using `apply` + `prod`

```
aa$prod <- apply(aa,1,prod)
```

or `cumprod`

```
aa$prod <- unlist(tail(cumprod(as.data.frame(t(aa))),1))
```

such that

```
> aa
  x y z prod
1 1 1 3    3
2 2 1 2    4
3 3 1 1    3
```